# Can I make Ctrl-I start italics the old way in VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

In earlier versions of Visual Studio, when using the HTML designer, pressing Ctrl-I with no text selected switched to italics for everything typed until Ctrl-I is pressed again. In VS2010, pressing Ctrl-I opens the style sheet file and modifies the current style. My customer keeps doing this and messing up the stylesheet for their entire web site. Is there any way to configure VS2010 to use the old method?

Answer (score 1):

Shortcuts was always and is still editable, so you can manually set it to whatever you desire.

Goto: Tools->Options->Keyboard.

I believe you'll there find what you're looking for.

Comment: But what do I change it to? Ctrl-I as standard applies italics to the current style. I just want it to insert <em>

Comment: If you have older version see what given commnad was mapped to. You can also try to simply select diferent mapping scheme altogether in the same dialog.

Comment: Not sure it's the mapping. Even clicking the italics I button in the toolbar updates the style in the stylesheet.